# Cannot copy folder in source dir to output dir

Tags: cmake

I want to copy a folder "obj_files" in my source dir to its output dir with the following code:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(projExec ${files_proj})

add_custom_command(TARGET projExec POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
                       ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/obj_files $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:projExec>)
```

but it doesn't work. The "CMakeLists.txt" with above commands lies in a subdirectory to another project, hence the output dir is a subdir to that project's output dir. Is this something to consider when attempting to do what I am trying to? Anyways, the problem is that the directory simply is nowhere to be found in the output dirs of the projects. No error messages when configurating/generating, the folder simply isn't copied.

Comment: `but it doesn't work` - **What exactly** is not working? Your command isn't executed? Or it is executed, but returns error? Or it is executed, but does not do what expected? Please, elaborate your problem.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for telling. Question has been edited

Comment: Note, that commands attached to target using `add_custom_command(TARGET)` flow are executed only when target file is regenerated. If target file is already up-to-date, such commands are ignored.